# How are non-split sequences of this form?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, exact-sequence

So, imagine we have 
$$0\to \mathbb{Z}_4 \to G \to \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_1}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_2}}\to 0$$
a short exact sequence that is not split. Then we know that $G$ is not a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_1}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_2}}$, but can we say that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_1+2}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_2}}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_1}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n_2+2}}$ or are there more possibilities?

Comment: There are other possibilities. For example $Z_2 \oplus Z_4 \oplus Z_8$ has a subgroup $Z_4$ (generated by $(1,0,2)$) with quotient $Z_4 \oplus Z_4$.